# How to change textview text from another activity on button click in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I have seen a lot of tutorials that gives answer for this, but I don't get it. It isn't working. I have a button in `MainActivity`, that has click listener that does this:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
     i.putExtra("Name", "RESULT");
     startActivity(i);
```

Another actiivty:

```
txtview = (TextView) find.....(R.id.textView1);
Intent i = getIntent();
String str = i.getStringExtra("Name");
txtview.setText(str);
```

I don't use an emulator, I build the apk and then transfer it to my mobile. So in my mobile when I click the button, it closes and says "The app is not responding"
XML:

```
<TextView
    android:text="result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="145dp"
    android:id="@+id/txt" />
```

Comment: check for null in second activity and also post your stacktrace

Comment: give us the code for DetailsActivity's onCreate method. Also the xml where textView1 is declared.

Comment: @John did it worked

Answer (score 0):

Change your TextView id to textView1.

findViewById method is returning null beacause there is no TextView with id textView1